# js call base class constructor

Tags: javascript, class

Is it possible to call a baseclass constructor from a class?

```
class BaseCls {
}

class Cls extend BaseCls {
    constructor(options){
        super(options)
    }
}

var instance = new Cls();
```

Now I want an instance of the baseclas. Something like this:

```
var baseInstance = new Cls.parent()
```

I know that I could just call new BaseCls(), but doing it the other way allows me to have only one import.

Comment: *Without* an instance of `Cls`? (That's what you've shown.)

Answer (score 4):

The superclass is the prototype of the subclass* (which is why superclass `static` methods are accessible on the subclass), so `Object.getPrototypeOf` will give you the superclass:

```js
class BaseCls {
    constructor() {
      console.log("BaseCls");
    }
}

class Cls extends BaseCls {
    constructor(options){
        super(options)
        console.log("Cls");
    }
}

var base = Object.getPrototypeOf(Cls);
var instance = new base();
```

You don't have to separate the statements, but if you want to combine them, you have to put `()` around the call to `Object.getPrototypeOf` (otherwise `new` tries to consume it):

```
var instance = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(Cls))();
```

And of course, if you wanted to do this generically from a reference to an instance of `Cls`, it would be:

```
var superInstance = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(instance.constructor))();
```

...provided `instance` doesn't have an own `constructor` property. Or the rather more convoluted:

```
var superInstance = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance).constructor))();
```

...if it may have its own `constructor` property.

---

* Yes, really. When you use `B extends A`, there are *two parallel* lines of inheritance set up: `A.prototype` is made the prototype of `B.prototype`, **and** `A` is made the prototype of `B` (whereas in ES5 and earlier, the prototype of a function was always `Function.prototype`).

Given:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}
```

the inheritance looks like this:

```
B −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> A −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> Function.prototype

B.prototype −−−−> A.prototype −−−−> Object.prototype
```

```js
class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === A);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A) === Function.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A.prototype) === Object.prototype);
```